# Angular, Jasmine : TypeError Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-material2

I'm trying to unit test the MatRadioGroup wrapper but keep getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined jasmine`.

The spec should pass but I don't get why filter undefined error being thrown while the test is being run.

Below is the spec:

```
it('should test the properties of the component', () => {
options = [
    {
        value: 'Option 1',
        displayValue: 'Option 1',
    }, {
        value: 'Option 2',
        displayValue: 'Option 2',
        checked: true,
    }
];
component.options = options;
component.color = 'primary';
fixture.detectChanges();
let radioElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.mat-radio-button'));
console.log(radioElement);
expect(radioElement.attributes['ng-reflect-color']).toEqual('primary');});
```

Here's the stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/radio-group-wrapper

Other suggestions for testing this wrapper are welcome.

Comment: Plz provide beforeEach and component code

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk you can find both in the stackblitz link.